# How to call Apify Google Search Scraper Task Using JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, apify

I am learning to use `apify/google-search-scraper` through their `API` call. The document is given [here](https://apify.com/docs/api/v2#/reference/actors/run-collection/run-actor).

I am bit confused with their documentation as I am new. Especially I need the help to configure the call. It

```
$.ajax({
   url : '',  
   method : "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

   data : {   

   },
   success:function(response) {
     console.log(response.data); 
   } 

 });
```

**url**: what should I write here?

**data** : Should I pass parameters here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [run task API endpoint](https://apify.com/docs/api/v2#/reference/actor-tasks/run-collection/run-task) to run it. You can use synchronous run same as asynchronous.

If you want to run the endpoint using AJAX you can use:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/<your task name>/runs?token=<your api token>',  
   method : 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success:function(response) {
     console.log(response.data); // Actor run object
   } 

 });
```

If you need to get data from task run as well you need to wait until it finishes. Then get data from default dataset using [get dataset items API endpoint](https://apify.com/docs/api/v2#/reference/datasets/item-collection/get-items). The good thing is that you can use `waitForFinish` param in calling run and it waits for it finishes.

```
const getItemsFromDataset = (datasetId) => {
    $.ajax({
       url : `https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/${datasetId}/items?format=json`,  
       method : 'GET',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       success:function(response) {
         console.log(response); // Items from dataset
       } 

     });
}

$.ajax({
   url : 'https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/<your task name>/runs?token=<your api token>&waitForFinish=120',  
   method : 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data : JSON.stringify ({
      "queries" : "query you want to"
   }),
   success:function(response) {
     console.log(response.data); // Actor run object
     getItemsFromDataset(response.data.defaultDatasetId) 
   } 

 });
```

You need to finish error handling in examples.

EDIT: Added queries param to override query you want to scrape.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What will I need to do if I want to add a task ( a new search)  from my app and then get the result?

Comment: You can simply override input with JSON payload of task run. You can do it with jQuery AJAX with adding data param. e.g.
data: {
     "queries": "apify crawler"
   }
You can see all the options in google search scraper doc(https://apify.com/apify/google-search-scraper).