# How to implement Apify webhooks?

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, apify

Need help to implement Apify [webhook](https://apify.com/docs/webhooks). It takes some time to complete a task. I want to add a Apify webhook which will run another task but not sure how to do that.

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/XXXXXXX/runs?token=XXXXXXXX&waitForFinish=120',  
  method : 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data : JSON.stringify ({
      "queries" : "Outreach link building"
  }),
  success:function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  } 
});
```

The webhook will then call the following task:

```
$.ajax({
   url : `https://api.apify.com/v2/datasets/${datasetId}/items?format=json`,  
   method : 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success:function(response) {
     console.log(response); // Items from dataset
   } 

 });
```

Btw if I am wrong with the way I want to implement what I need, please let me know your suggestion.

Comment: The webhook doesn't call any task. It simply sends a "notification" to your endpoint that the run has finished. You need to have some kind of server to listen for the webhook.

Comment: Understood.  Can I get some code example?  Say after running the actor, I will store the datasetId in my database. Once the actor build is completed, I want the hook sends a notification to an url of my app. Based on the notification I will update the status of the datasetId.

Comment: Wouldn't be then better to do the integration with Apify via your server and then communicate it to your front-end?

Comment: Ya, I will do it via my server.  How will I know that the dataset is ready after running the actor?

Comment: There are items pushed to the dataset from the moment you start the run. So just poll it every second and display the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a server at all underneath your application and you want to manage everything on from the client-side (front-end) and the 5 minutes max delay for the synchronous run it too short for you, you can use polling. You simply call the run endpoint few times until it will return with the status succeeded.

But if you can you the `waitForFinish`, just do that and then send the second call to get the dataset in the

```
success:function(result) {
    console.log(result);
   // instead of this log, you need to put your second call here and use the `result.data.defaultDatasetId` as ID of the dataset
  }
```

If you have to wait longer than 300 seconds, you will need to use polling. But I would really avoid that or don't use ajax with callbacks but more modern [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/XXXXXXX/runs?token=XXXXXXXX&waitForFinish=120',  
  method : 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data : JSON.stringify ({
      "queries" : "Outreach link building"
  }),
  success:function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    // Here instead of just logging, you get the run object back with its `status`. You also find an `id` there and you can periodically poll the run with this endpoint
https://apify.com/docs/api/v2#/reference/actors/run-object/get-run

  }
```

Comment: The app will store information in its database. Log is used here to test the result.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848672/how-to-call-apify-google-search-scrapper-task-using-jquery-ajax/57848885?noredirect=1#comment102125590_57848885)? If yes, I actually would like to have a better user experience. Rather than keeping the user waiting to see things happen, I would like calll the dataset programmatically when it is ready.  Can I do that?

Comment: Also I have edited my question, would you please check and let me know if the code is right?

Comment: You can call the dataset in some interval and update the displayed data.